# problem in defining regular expression

Tags: php, regex

How to define regular expression of mathematical expression.please define a common regular expression for

```
5+4
5-3
5*6
6/2
```

Comment: can the mathematical expression be more complicated or just
number operator number?

Comment: you wanna allow spaces between numbers and operators? are decimals supported?

Comment: Your "question" lacks a lot of detail. What do you want to use it for? do you need to capture part of the expression or split it?  When writing questions you should try and add as much detail as possible, help us to help you.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, here's one which might be a bit more complicated than you need *(hey, it's a regex!)*

```
/^\s*-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:\s*[+*\/\-]\s*-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)+(?:\s*=\s*-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)?$/
```

It allows for one or more operations, decimal numbers, and optionally an "equals" part at the end.

```
5 + 7
3 * 2 - 8
80.31 + 12 / 6
5 * 7 - 2 = 33
```

Comment: `<nit-picking>` It doesn't support negative numbers `</nit-picking>`

Answer (score 0):

```
^\d+[+*\-/]\d+$
```

Comment: `+` is not a meta character inside a character class - need not be escaped. `-` is a meta character inside a character class and need to be escaped unless it is the first or last character in the class.  `^\d+[+*/-]\d+$` or `^\d+[+*\-/]\d+$` or `^\d+[-+*/]\d+$`

Comment: `(\d)+` will match and capture one digit at a time, so only the last digit is retained.  If you want to capture the whole number, put the plus sign inside the parens: `(\d+)`; if you don't want to capture it, get rid of the parens because they're just creating a lot of extra work for the regex engine.

Comment: The regex engines will look up and shout "Save us," and I'll whisper… "No."

Comment: :) For some reason I tend to answer questions even if I don't really familiar with the subject. I hardly use regex in my code :)

Comment: Don't stop doing that.. that's how you learn - at least that's how I learned regex. Once learned, you'll start looking for a chance to use regex - at least I did.

Answer (score 0):

The specification is vague, but here's a readable regex using meta-regexing approach in Java.

```
    String regex =
        "num(?:opnum)*"
            .replace("op", "\\s*[*/+-]\\s*")
            .replace("num", "\\s*[+-]?\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?\\s*");
    String[] tests = {
        "5+4",          // true
        "5 - 3",        // true
        "5 * 6 - 4",    // true
        "3.14159 = 0",  // true
        "A = B",        // false
        "5+ -4",        // true
        "5 * +4",       // true
        "5++5",         // true
        "5+++5",        // false
        "5+5+"          // false
    };
    for (String test : tests) {
        System.out.println(test + " " + test.matches(regex));
    }
```

Numbers may include optional decimal part, and a `+/-` sign. There could be multiple equalities.